# Adding Bind Event To Entry Fields Created Using Loops

Tags: python, function, tkinter, tk-toolkit

The main aim here is too bind events to entry fields which are created dynamically using loops and then fetch the values from those fields, how ever i am having issues here to create a function  that grabs the text from the entry field as soon as  the user starts typing in the box.

```
from tkinter import Tk, LEFT, BOTH, StringVar
from tkinter.ttk import Entry, Frame
import functools


class Example(Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.parent = parent
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.parent.title("Entry")
        self.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)
        self.contents = []
        self.ent = []
        for i in range(0,5):
            self.contents.append(StringVar())

        # give the StringVar a default value
        for i in range(0,5):
            self.entry = Entry(self)
            self.entry.grid(row=0,column=i)
            self.entry["textvariable"] = self.contents[i]
            self.entry.bind('<KeyRelease>', self.on_changed)
            self.ent.append(self.entry)

    def on_changed(self, event):
        print('contents: {}'.format(self.contents.get()))
        return True
def main():
    root = Tk()
    ex = Example(root)
    root.geometry("800x400")
    root.mainloop()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 1):

When you use `bind`, the event object that is passed to the callback includes a reference to the widget, which you can use to get the value of the entry.

**Example**

```
def on_changed(self, event):
    entry = event.widget
    print('contents: {}'.format(entry.get()))
    return True
```

Comment: Thanks Mahn!! I had no idea about this widget reference!!